# Transform a 3M FRA Rate to a 6M FRA Rate

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap, forward-rate, bootstrapping

I have a question whether it is possible to transform 3M FRA rates to 6M FRA rates without having any spreads available. Let's give an example:

FRA 3M:

FRA 1x4
FRA 2x5
FRA 3x6
FRA 4x7
FRA 5x8
FRA 6x9

And what I need to calculate is:

FRA 6M:

FRA 1x7
FRA 2x8
FRA 3x9
FRA 4x10
FRA 5x11

Is there a possibility doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a pure mathematical perspective, this is possible. For example, consider dates $t_0 \le t_1 < t_2 < t_3$. Given
\begin{align*}
L(t_0, t_1, t_2) = \frac{1}{\Delta t_2}\left(\frac{P(t_0, t_1)}{P(t_0, t_2)}-1 \right),
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
L(t_0, t_2, t_3) = \frac{1}{\Delta t_3}\left(\frac{P(t_0, t_2)}{P(t_0, t_3)}-1 \right),
\end{align*}
where $\Delta t_i = t_i-t_{i-1}$, and $P(t, u)$ is the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond with maturity $u$ and unit face value.

Then
\begin{align*}
L(t_0, t_1, t_3) &= \frac{1}{t_3-t_1}\left(\frac{P(t_0, t_1)}{P(t_0, t_3)}-1 \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{t_3-t_1}\left(\frac{P(t_0, t_1)}{P(t_0, t_2)}\frac{P(t_0, t_2)}{P(t_0, t_2)}-1 \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{t_3-t_1}\Big(\big(1+\Delta t_2 L(t_0, t_1, t_2)\big)\big(1+\Delta t_3 L(t_0, t_2, t_3) \big)-1 \Big).
\end{align*}

For example,  assuming 30 days a month and the day-count convention is 30/360. If FRA $1\times 4$ is 4% and FRA $4\times 7$ is 5%, then
\begin{align*}
FRA \,1\times 7 &=\frac{1}{0.5}\Big(\big(1+0.25\times 0.04)\big)\big(1+0.25 \times 0.05 \big)-1 \Big)\\
&=0.04525,
\end{align*}
that is, 4.525%.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The 3M and 6M are the tenors not the maturity. Or do I misundertand something? Furthermore, do you have a numerical example?

Comment: you can consider converting FRA 1x4 and 4x7 to FRA 1x7, assuming 30 days a month and the day-count convention is 30/360.

Comment: Thanks Gordan, I am a little bit new in the bsuines.Can you show a simple example with values? It does not need to be exact or maybe in QuantLib?

Comment: See the updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. Just some more silly questions. How die you derive the values 0.5 and 0.25 numerically?

Comment: 0.5 for 6 months and 0.25 for 3 months

Comment: Thanks. But where are the day count conventions and the 30 days a month aplaying a role in the equoation?

Comment: you assume 30 days in a month and 360 days in a year. then 6 months is 0.5 yrs and 3  months is 0.25 yrs.

Comment: Perect! Thanks a lot. That means \begin{align*}
{\Delta t_i}
\end{align*} is just the day-count conventions. Which also can be Act/360 etc...

Comment: It can be any thing based on the specification, for example, act/360, act/365, or 30/360 etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is that also in the practise the way how it works?

Comment: Yes, in practice, the dates are specifically defined and the day-convention is also specified. Based on these, you can compute $\Delta t_i$.

Comment: Sorry for asking again. Do you have a simple practise example.

Comment: I do not have such practical examples, but please check any books on interest rates.

Comment: One more question. Do I have to discount that quote to receive the proper 1x7 FRA rate? Furthermore, does the implied quote has to be exact the same as the market quote when comparing it? I have some BP difference. I think this is the result of the basis spread between 3M vs. 6M

Comment: You may ask this as another question. I do not think you need to discount as is shown by the mathematical formula. It may not be the same as the market quote, as the longer tenor may have certain liquidity risk and other risks.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will try asking antoher question concerning te spread

Comment: I fundamentally disagree with this answer. An FRA is an IBOR based derivative and 6M IBOR versus 3M IBOR requires a spread instrument to distinguish those prices in every currency market. Therefore the simple answer is without a basis you cannot price 6M FRAs from 3M FRAs.

Comment: @Attack68: I am looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

An FRA (forward rate agreement) is an interest rate derivative contract with specific documentation. A 3M FRA settles to 3M-IBOR, and a 6M FRA settles to 6M-IBOR, not a 6M rate that is a compounded composite rate of two 3M periods.

Gordon's answer does as much as you can with the given information: it transforms a 3M rate into a 6M 'period' with compositions, but the resulting rate suffers the inherent problem it does not represent 6M-IBOR. My opinion is that the difference (not just spot but also forward) in the 3M-IBOR/6M-IBOR basis is so important in these prices that the specific question stating "without having any [basis] spread available" means you cannot determine the specific prices of 6M FRAs.

In all major currencies, GBP, USD, EUR and JPY the 6M-IBOR basis is different in spot and forward levels leaving scope for a lot of variability. As a trader I would never price a 6M FRA with only the information of 3M FRAs.

An analogy is deriving the yields of French government bonds compared to German government bonds without having the country spread available. You can make some sensible estimations and derive some general conclusions but you can't 'price' them.